# Scroll problems with multi ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I am a beginner in WPF, around 2 hours life:) and already got this problem.
I want to do something "similar" to Bootstrap with a list of orders and inside every order a list of products.
I'm managing that with a ListView inside other ListView, but I can not get any of my scrolls works now. How can I get my scroll working?

> Note: This is for tablets use (touch), I hid the scroll intentionally.

[image]

This is my actual code

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding HardwareList}"  Name="ListHardware" Margin="12,132,12,12" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="235">
                    <Grid Height="220" Width="1338"  Background="#fbe8e5" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Border BorderBrush="#dd4b39" BorderThickness="1"  CornerRadius="3">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid Height="39" Width="1338" Background="#dd4b39" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label Content="Stock Picking:" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"></Label>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding  Order}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"  FontSize="18"></Label>
                                    <Label Content="[Imported]" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Foreground="White"  FontSize="18"></Label>
                                </Grid>
                                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Hardwares}" Name="Hardware" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid Height="151" Width="318" Margin="12,50,0,12">                                                    
                                                <Button Content="{Binding  Name}"></Button>
                                            </Grid>                                                
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">                                                
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                                                        <ContentPresenter />
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                </ListView> 
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>  
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">                    
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>                    
            </Style>                
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

And on the .cs class something simple so far

```
private void LoadHardware()
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        HardwareList hardwareList = new HardwareList();
        hardwareList.Order = "Order/10472" + i;
        hardwareList.Status = "Done-"+ i;
        List<Hardware> hardwares = new List<Hardware>();                
        for (int j = 0; j < 10j++)
        {
            Hardware hardware = new Hardware();
            hardware.Name = "product_00"+j;
            hardware.Qty = "20";                    
            hardwares.Add(hardware);                    
        }
        hardwareList.Hardwares = hardwares;                
        ListHardware.Items.Add(hardwareList);            
    }      
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what your image is trying to show.

Comment: Change Background to `Transparent` instead of `{x:Null}` to get your HitTestVisibility back, at first glance that appears the possible culprit.

Comment: With the image, I just wanna show when I try to click and scroll nothing happen. I change the background look the same but nothing different happened :(

Comment: Oh dude, I'm sorry I didn't notice before, change your `ScrollbarVisibility` to `Hidden` instead of `Disabled` on each ListView and you should be sorted unless maybe you have something else not shown deferring the hittestvisibility

Comment: Never mind guys I change all the view and put all inside WrapPanel, I will see always the internal list and just one scroll for the big ones... ty :)